# ANDROID (Java) - Progress bar visibility on page finished loading not working?

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, visibility

The progress bar and webview works fine but when the page is finished loading the progress bar still remains? When I have loaded the page the progress bar visibility doesn't dissapear/change to GONE? Where is the error?

```
package za.co.test.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class KlokTyd extends Activity{

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.klok_tyd);

        WebView ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ourBrow.loadUrl("http://example.blogspot.com/");

    }

       public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient 
       {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

       }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a class that extends `WebViewClient` but you never use it. Pass an instance of your own class (`myWebViewClient`) to `setWebViewClient()`. Change the line

```
ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

to

```
ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
```

Comment: myWebViewClient cannot be resolved to a type? I know I'm an idiot but I'm kindof stuck xD

Comment: @HoërskoolEldoraigne sorry that was a typo your class is actually called `myWebClient`. I'll edit the awnser.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It works, I'm still new to java so thanks a lot :)